# Extraer quirúrjicamente un archivo de un determinado hash

Tags: git

Para obtener un fichero del histórico de git tengo dos opciones pero ninguna me termina de convencer:

- La primera es utilizar `git show` y redireccionar el output `git show hash:bigfile.zip > bigfile.bak.zip` pero para ficheros grandes no lo veo útil.
- La segunda es hacer un `checkout hash bigfile.zip` para retroceder al estado el fichero y luego tener que deshacerme del cambio.

Mi pregunta es: **¿existe alguna otra manera limpia de simplemente traerse un fichero en un momento determinado?**

Comment: La primera es la forma apropiada de hacerlo si lo quieres poner en un archivo que _no es el original_. Si lo quieres poner en el archivo original (o sea, con el mismo nombre en tu arbol de trabajo), podrías hacer: `git restore --worktree --source=el-hash -- bigfile.zip`.

Comment: Desconocia el comando `restore`, Me ha sido de gran utilidad.
Ahora me cuestiono si vale la pena utilizar `lfs` para un git local que maneja archivos binarios y grandes, no termino de entender si se utiliza para hacer backup en servidores remotos y solo para algo local no termina de ser util

Comment: `git lsf` se utiliza (hasta lo mejor de mi conocimiento... en realidad nunca lo he necesitado) si vas a hacer alojamiento en servicios como github que no te permiten subir archivos de cierto tamaño (en el caso de github, 100 MBs).

Comment: Y `git restore` es algo relativamente reciente.... no es de hace 2 días, pero no tiene 5 años, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Me di a la tarea de hacer un ejemplo, pero short anwser:

```
git restore -s <revision> -- <archivo>
```

Por ejemplo, si primero creamos un commit con un archivo, y en otro commit lo eliminamos, lo podemos restaurar como describe la imagen (perdón por usar imágenes de terminal, pero me permite usar flechitas):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde el comando mágico fue:

```
git restore -s ":/archivo a recuperar" -- archivo_a_recuperar
```

Donde yo use como valor de `-s` el mensaje del commit, pero podemos usar el hash del commit o la rama o alguna otra revisión.